# Append objects to HTML

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML and a JS file, and I am trying to append an object to HTML. But when the button is clicked, the message is "undefined:undefined" instead of "Me:Hello!"

Advice and help are very appreciated.

```
var button = document.querySelector("#send");
var messages = document.querySelector("#messages");
var message =  {
  name: "Me",
  message: "Hello"
}

function sendMessage (message) {
  messages.append(message.name + ":" + message.message);
}

button.addEventListener("click", sendMessage, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass message argument in your function as it's a global variable. change your function as below:

```
function sendMessage() {
  messages.append(message.name + ":" + message.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `message` variable declared in the argument of `sendMessage` masks the global `message` variable declared with `var` on line 3.

The first argument to an event handler function receives the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object when the event handler fires.

Name the argument something different (`e` and `event` are traditional choices) so you have access to the global variable.